# Cant access NFS share with non-root user

Tags: permissions, nfs, webmin

I have mounted an NFS network share successfully using Webmin.  The share seems to be mounted correctly and working correctly.  If I login as root I can browse the share just fine.

However, I cannot seem to give another user access to read/write to this network share.  When I look at the permissions I can see that it is owned by root and the group crontab can use the share.

```
$ ls -las

4 drwxr-xr-x   3 root root    4096 Nov 11 23:35 .
4 drwxr-xr-x  23 root root    4096 Nov 11 23:35 ..
8 drwxrwx---+ 23 root crontab 4096 Feb 15  2013 private
```

So just to test thing out, I added crontab to my user scott.

```
$ groups

scott adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev crontab lpadmin sambashare
```

however I still can't access the share.

```
$ cd private/

-bash: cd: private/: Permission denied
```

Any ideas?

Comment: run the command as a root user.

Comment: thanks for the response, but as I said, "If I login as root I can browse the share just fine."  This is not the goal, I need to give a specific user permission to access the share.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by adding the user group to the ACL.  I also modified the default group permissions so new files will also be accessible in the future.

Fist installed acl

```
sudo apt-get install acl
```

Changed the permissions

```
sudo setfacl -d -Rm g:nas:rwx  private/

# -d to change the directory default.
# -R for recursive
# -m g:nas:rwx to add the group to the ACL list for folder private/
```

I verified the changes:

```
sudo getfacl private/
```

Comment: Not that it makes much difference now, but it's probably worth noting that Linux includes an option to have the server side check for group membership rather than the client side.  So, if nfsd was started with the `–manage-gids` option, client-side group membership doesn't matter.  Applying the ACL gave access to a different group which I suspect (you said "the user group") the user may well have been a member of on the server side.